# Как сделать рамку в ListView?

Tags: android

Как сделать рамку вокруг элемента?
Получить мне нужно что-то типа следующего:
[image]
Интересует как можно сделать такую рамку по габаритам элемента списка и как сделать отдельную рамку до конца экрана

**UPD**
Кстати, возможно ли как-то удалить логотип приложения, чтобы он в actionBar не всплывал?
**UPD2**

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

       menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.reload_button);
       menuItem.setEnabled(true);
       menuItem.setVisible(true);

       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

       return true;
    }
```

А вот xml:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

       <item
            android:id="@+id/reload_button"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate">
       </item>

    </menu>
```

Comment: Это называется `nine-patch` — особым образом сформированный `png` файл со служебной разметкой, задающей правила `stretching`'а и расположения внутреннего контента. Подробнее читайте в документации.

Comment: А просто создать хоть кукую рамку в listView не получится?

Comment: Сделать `shape` с рамкой (`stroke`) и поставить на `background` у `ListView`. Также можно применить этот `shape` и к элементам `ListView`.

Comment: [вот здесь все что тебе нужно ][1]

[доки][2]


  [1]: http://megadarja.blogspot.ru/2011/03/android-xml-drawables.html
  [2]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: Вопрос офтопом: возможно ли как-то удалить логотип приложения, чтобы он в actionBar вообще не показывался?

Comment: в манифеесте убрать иконку

Comment: `android:icon="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: @Stas0n, это прописать в манифесте в теге с вашей активити

Comment: В `onCreateOptionsMenu` прописать
> getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

Сделав до этого `res/menu/main_menu.xml` с описанием атрибутов меню.
И в `onOptionsItemSelected` ловить нажатие по кнопке.

Comment: @Stas0n, `IndexOutOfBoundException` возникает потому, что вам следует использовать `menu.findItem()`, `getItem()` же в качестве параметра ожидает индекс.

Comment: @falstaf  использую menu.findItem() в onOptionsItemSelected , после чего menu.setVisible(true);  Выпадает эксепшн, в setVisible - nullPointerexception

Comment: @Stas0n, возможно, ищете не по тому `id`, который указан в XML меню. В любом случае, без кода и XML сложно что-то определённое сказать.

Comment: добавил код и xml

Comment: Вы пытаетесь работать с пунктами меню до его фактического добавления. Перенесите строку с `getMenuInflater().inflate()` в начало метода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.reload_button);
    menuItem.setEnabled(true);
    menuItem.setVisible(true);

    return true;
```

}

Этот код не отображает reloadbutton

Comment: Давайте-ка вы лучше создадите отдельный вопрос и не будем более в этом оффтопить.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, собственно, вот что получилось:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#ffffff" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#808080" />
```

[image]

Comment: подскажи куда этот xml положить? везде пробовал ошибку выдает